# Is speaking about a fraction of the boundary of the mandelbrot set meaningful?

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, fractals

Sorry if my question is vague, as I have very little background with fractals and measure theory. My question is inspired by a tweet, where a light shone onto the mandelbrot set, and certain rays were blocked upon intersection with the set. One commenter asked what the maximum "fraction" of the total set would be "visible" to the light. That is, what proportion of the perimeter of the set would contain intersections with the light ray. I was uneasy with this question, as I was not sure if speaking of such proportions would be meaningful. For instance, I know that speaking of "fraction of natural numbers n such that n ≡ 0 (mod 3) is not strictly answerable, as there is no uniform measure on the naturals.

TL;DR: Is there a meaningful way to speak about a "fraction" of the boundary of the Mandelbrot set?

Comment: In general, we ask that users provide context for their questions.  In this case, you have mentioned a tweet which inspired this question.  Can you please edit your question to include a link to that tweet?

Comment: This is not really my area of expertise, but my recollection is that the boundary of the Mandelbrot set has Hausdorff dimension 2, but that the question of whether or not the boundary has positive measure is still open (though I seem to recall that some progress was made about a decade ago, so it could be that this has been resolved).  If the boundary has positive measure, then we could meaningfully talk about proportions of the boundary.

Comment: This is very far from my area of expertise, but I recall that people considered the boundary of the Mandelbrot set as parametrized by external rays (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_ray). Maybe the asymptotic directions of those rays could provide a sensible probability distribution on the Mandelbrot boundary.

Comment: I think it's still open whether all rays land on the boundary of the Mandelbrot set - all rational rays do, landing on Misiurewicz points (preperiodic angles under doubling) and roots of hyperbolic components (periodic angles), but there are irrational rays too.